# excel vba Method Range of object _worksheet failed when range string is too long

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to run this function to get the string range I get the error message:`"Method Range of object _Worksheet failed.`
I am running excel 2013 and MSVBA 7.1

This is my code:

```
Public Function dataRange() As Range
  Dim activeMonth As Date, sht As Worksheet, s As String, r As Range
  activeMonth = Format(Now, "MMM-YYYY")
  Set sht = Sheets(Format(Now, "MMM-YYYY"))
  s = ""
  s = "$b$6:$bm$6,$B$9:$Bm$9,$B$12:$Bm$12,$b$15:$bm$15,$B$18:$Bm$18,$b$21:$bm$21,$b$24:$bm$24,$b$27:$bm$27,$b$30:$bm$30,$b$33:$bm$33,"
  s = s & "$B$36:$Bm$36,$B$39:$Bm$39,$B$42:$Bm$42,$B$45:$Bm$45,$B$48:$Bm$48,$B$51:$Bm$51,$B$54:$Bm$54,$B$57:$Bm$57,$B$60:$Bm$60,$B$63:$Bm$63,$B$66:$Bm$66,$B$69:$Bm$69"
  s = s & "$B$72:$BO$72,$B$75:$BO$75,$B$78:$BO$78,$B$81:$BO$81,$B$84:$BO$84,$B$87:$BO$87,$B$90:$BO$90,$B$93:$BO$93,$B$96:$BO$96"
  Set r = sht.Range(s) 'THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR..

 'SO I TRIED THE CODE BELOW BUT IT STILL WON'T PRINT THE WHOLE STRING IN THE DEBUG AREA!!

  Dim r1, r2, r3 As Range
  s = ""
  Set r1 = sht.Range("$b$6:$bm$6,$B$9:$Bm$9,$B$12:$Bm$12,$b$15:$bm$15,$B$18:$Bm$18,$b$21:$bm$21,$b$24:$bm$24,$b$27:$bm$27,$b$30:$bm$30,$b$33:$bm$33")
  Set r2 = sht.Range("$B$36:$Bm$36,$B$39:$Bm$39,$B$42:$Bm$42,$B$45:$Bm$45,$B$48:$Bm$48,$B$51:$Bm$51,$B$54:$Bm$54,$B$57:$Bm$57,$B$60:$Bm$60,$B$63:$Bm$63,$B$66:$Bm$66,$B$69:$Bm$69")
  Set r3 = sht.Range("$B$72:$BO$72,$B$75:$BO$75,$B$78:$BO$78,$B$81:$BO$81,$B$84:$BO$84,$B$87:$BO$87,$B$90:$BO$90,$B$93:$BO$93,$B$96:$BO$96")
  Set r = Union(r1, r2, r3)
  Debug.Print r.Address 'THIS WILL PRINT THE ADDRESS PARTIALLY:
'$B$6:$BM$6,$B$9:$BM$9,$B$12:$BM$12,$B$15:$BM$15,$B$18:$BM$18,$B$21:$BM$21,$B$24:$BM$24,$B$27:$BM$27,$B$30:$BM$30,$B$33:$BM$33,$B$36:$BM$36,$B$39:$BM$39,$B$42:$BM$42,$B$45:$BM$45,$B$48:$BM$48,$B$51:$BM$51,$B$54:$BM$54,$B$57:$BM$57,$B$60:$BM$60,$B$63:$BM$63

  Set dataRange = r

End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Range limit conundrum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663264/range-limit-conundrum)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function dataRange() As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet, rv As Range, r As Range
  Dim i as long

  Set sht = Sheets(Format(Now, "MMM-YYYY"))

  for i=6 to 96 step 3
      Set r = sht.Range("b" & i ":bm" & i)
      if rv is nothing then
          Set rv = r
      else
          Set rv = Application.Union(rv.r)
      end if
  Next i

  Set dataRange = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some limits with range objects which require to use the `Union` function as you observe.  I'm not sure exactly what it is for 2013 but I seem to recall a 255 character limit in previous versions of Excel (could be mistaken). In any case, that would explain the error assigning to the range, and it will also explain why the `r.Address` seems to truncate your results.

Use the `Union` function in a loop, and if you need to debug to verify that the address string is accurate, you will need to assign back to a string variable, also in a loop over the range's `.Areas` collection:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Range

    s = ""


    Set r = Range("B6:BM9") 'initial range

    For i = 9 To 96 Step 3
        Set r = Union(r, Range("$B$" & i & ":$BM$" & i))
    Next

    'If you need to *see* the range address, you'll need to reconstruct it

    For Each a In r.Areas
        If Not s = vbNullString Then
            s = s & "," & a.Address
        Else
            s = a.Address
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print r.Address

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

This prints the following for `r` (which truncates):

```
$B$6:$BM$9,$B$12:$BM$12,$B$15:$BM$15,$B$18:$BM$18,$B$21:$BM$21,$B$24:$BM$24,$B$27:$BM$27,$B$30:$BM$30,$B$33:$BM$33,$B$36:$BM$36,$B$39:$BM$39,$B$42:$BM$42,$B$45:$BM$45,$B$48:$BM$48,$B$51:$BM$51,$B$54:$BM$54,$B$57:$BM$57,$B$60:$BM$60,$B$63:$BM$63,$B$66:$BM$66
```

This prints the following for `s`

```
$B$6:$BM$9,$B$12:$BM$12,$B$15:$BM$15,$B$18:$BM$18,$B$21:$BM$21,$B$24:$BM$24,$B$27:$BM$27,$B$30:$BM$30,$B$33:$BM$33,$B$36:$BM$36,$B$39:$BM$39,$B$42:$BM$42,$B$45:$BM$45,$B$48:$BM$48,$B$51:$BM$51,$B$54:$BM$54,$B$57:$BM$57,$B$60:$BM$60,$B$63:$BM$63,$B$66:$BM$66,$B$69:$BM$69,$B$72:$BM$72,$B$75:$BM$75,$B$78:$BM$78,$B$81:$BM$81,$B$84:$BM$84,$B$87:$BM$87,$B$90:$BM$90,$B$93:$BM$93,$B$96:$BM$96
```