# Visual bug? Excel-vba AllowEditRange with many areas

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this code:

```
Sub AerTest()
'aer = allow edit range
Dim c, aerMain As Range

Set aerMain = Range("A1")

For Each c In Range("A1:AI23")
    If c.Value = 1 Then
        Set aerMain = Union(c, aerMain)
    End If
Next c

ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Test", Range:=aerMain

End Sub
```

I expect under review -> Allow Edit Ranges to find something call "Test" which contains all the cells with a 1 in them, in the relevant range (A1:AI23).

In terms of functionality it seems to work. All cells containing a 1 can be altered when the sheet is locked.

However, as shown below, it does not the correct thing is happening, i.e. it only shows a few areas of the range it should. It appears that the field "Refers to cells" only contains something like

```
=$AI$23;$AG$23;$AE$23;$AC$23;$AA$23;$Y$23;$W$23;$U$23;$S$23;$Q$23;$O$23;$M$23;$K$23;$I$23;$G$23;$E$23;$C$23;$A$23;$AI$21;$AG$21;$AE$21;$AC$21;$AA$21;$Y$21;$W$21;$U$21;$S$21;$Q$21;$O$21;$M$21;$K$21;$I$21;$G$21;$E$21;$C$21;$A$21;$AI$19;$AG$19;$AE$19;$AC$19
```

which clearly does not contain all the relevant cells (such as "A1").

If i go the the menu shown below and press OK rather then Cancel, I lose the functionality of having all cells containing a 1 editable when the sheet is locked, and then I will in fact only be able to edit the fields in the this in the field "Refers to cell".

Is this purely a visual bug, or are there other approaches to allow edit ranges that avoid these quirks when dealing with a range with many areas?

[image: The result when running the above code]

Comment: It will be a 255-character limitation.  If you google "site:stackoverflow.com excel-vba maximum characters in a range name" you will find numerous cases where it has occurred.  (e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26345127/6535336))

Answer (score 1):

I found some documentation from Microsoft re [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).  The important part says:

> **Name length**    A name can contain up to 255 characters.

As far as Excel is concerned, `=$AI$23;$AG$23;$AE$23;$AC$23;$AA$23;$Y$23...` is just another range name, and thus is limited to the 255 characters.

Your `AllowEditRanges.Add` will work, because that is actually working with the range itself and not via the range name, but the name being added will be truncated to the 255 characters.