# Error when referring to many multiple named ranges in Range property

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I have around 236 named ranges (columns) for a large table of data. I get this error when trying to split up the long code-line of delimited named ranges:

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

E.g.:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("foo1,foo2" _
    & "foo3,foo4" _
    & "..." _
    & "foo235,foo236")
```

I am trying to filter and unfilter columns based on specific criteria (named ranges). Everything seems to work fine (for smaller strings that only span 1 line in length) until I have to split the code into multiple lines since it reaches the end of the window..

Code -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Fruit," _
            & "Months,Colour").EntireColumn.Hidden = Target.Value = "CustomView"
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Colour,Number" _
            & "Months").EntireColumn.Hidden = Target.Value = "Custom2View"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code doesn't seem to work. I think it has something to do with the quotes and how excel reads it but i haven't been able to find a fix yet.

New code being tested based on suggestions in comments results in an error Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim arr, i As Long, rng As Range

If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
    arr = Split("foo1,foo2,foo3,...,foo266,foo267", ",")
 Set rng = Worksheets("Database").Range(arr(0))
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
 Set rng = Application.Union(rng, Worksheets("Database").Range(arr(i)))
 Next i
 rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "CustomView")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @TimWilliams I get a run-time error '1004' Application-define or object-defined error dialogue box and then when i go to debug, it highlights the entire section from worksheets onwards

Comment: The first block looks OK, but the second one is missing a comma after "Number".  FYI if this code is in Sheet1 then you can use `Me` in place of ` Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Neither the first block or the second works. I tried something different where i split the line in between text rather than at the ends (this fixed the issue where i think the location of the quotes are a concern) which worked for a small data range, but for the 100+ named ranges in the brackets it runs into errors again. Thanks for the suggestion about the sheet name.

Comment: @ThomasTcred - I edited your question I think it needed to be more obvious that the problem is with the 100+ named ranges and not just Fruit, Months, Colour etc. Hope the edit is OK - feel free to rollback if not

Comment: Thanks @RobinMackenzie , yes the major issue seems to be because of the many named ranges i need to use within the brackets. appreciate it

Comment: You cannot pass more than 255 characters to the `Range()` method.  Eg; see https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/437853-what-limits-when-creating-range-vba.html

Comment: any suggestions as to how i can still accomplish hiding columns by named ranges (columns), my table changes quite often so limiting it to identifying the columns by cell location doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Range limit conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663264/range-limit-conundrum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Union` to build up a range and then hide/show that range in one shot.

EDIT: based on your second shared file I think you need something like this.  Your previous code was not checking the value of the "view name" cell and was applying all of the views, leaving you with the last one...

Eg:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim arr, q As Long, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets("Database")

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then

        'unhide all columns forst
        sht.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "CustomView"
                arr = Split("A,B,C_,X,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM," & _
                  "AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG," & _
                  "BH,BI,BJ,BK,BL,BM,BN,BO,BP,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BU,BV,BW,BX,BY,BZ,CA," & _
                  "CB,CC,CD,CE,CF,CG,CH,CI,CJ,CK,CL,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,DA,DB,DC", ",")
            Case "XX100View"
                arr = Split("D,E,F,G,X,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO," & _
                   "AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ," & _
                   "BK,BL,BM,BN,BO,BP,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BU,BV,BW,BX,BY,BZ,CA,CB,CC,CD,CE," & _
                   "CF,CG,CH,CI,CJ,CK,CL,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,DA,DB,DC", ",")
            Case "OtherView"
                arr = Split("A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,X,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM," & _
                    "AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH," & _
                    "BI,BJ,BK,BL,BM,BN,BO,BP,BQ,BR,BS,BT,BU,BV,BW,BX,BY,BZ,CA,CB," & _
                    "CC,CD,CE,CF,CG,CH,CI,CJ,CK,CL,CU,CV,CW,CX,CY,CZ,DA,DB,DC", ",")
        End Select

        If Not IsEmpty(arr) Then
            Set rng = sht.Range(arr(0))
            For q = 1 To UBound(arr)
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, sht.Range(arr(q)))
            Next q
            rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True '<<edited
        End If 'got a view

    End If 'is view name cell
End Sub
```

PS - your range names don't need to include all of your data: a single cell would be fine, since you use `EntireColumn` to expand it to the entire sheet height anyway.

Comment: Hi TIm i'm not familiar yet with the application.union method so troubleshooting it is difficult. I get an error indicating "Compile error: Invalid next control variable reference" and it highlights onto the 'Next v' line - i fixed this assuming it was supposed to be 'Next i, but then i got a Run-time Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object 'Works - fixed the database name to include Worksheets("Database") as the name of the sheet was different - now i have a run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error and it highlights the 'Set rng = Application.Union(rng, Wor..) line.

Comment: Can you update your question to add the exact code you're trying?

Comment: Are the columns you're hiding on the same sheet as the cell triggering the event?

Comment: i've edited the question above now. the columns I am trying to hide are on a separate worksheet named 'Database', my view-selector has to be on a separate sheet from the table as it is used to pre-select what columns get hidden but since this is a table i cant use custom-views so trying to create this code as a workaround. Please note i changed the v to an i, and added in the worksheet name while trying to identify those errors.

Comment: Does the error occur on a specific value of i, and does the corresponding range name exists on the database sheet?

Comment: I do have the letter i being used as a variable for an integer as part of different code in a module2 on the same sheet. and the error starts off right away without letting me run the code

Comment: the error was on the line 'Set rng = Application.union(rng, worksheets(...))

Comment: That would tend to indicate there's no range with whatever name is in `arr(i)` when it fails.  Are you able to share the workbook?

Comment: I cant share the exact workbook itself, but i was using a test file that i can share. Do i email it to you? (i dont have reputation here to move this to a chat). i'm including some of the code that is in the file, in case different codes are causing the error - after updating the code in the sample file, now the code just runs and doesnt seem to do anything at all, (no errors) but doesnt do what is intended @Tim

Comment: It's best to share the file via dropbox/box/google drive etc if you can.

Comment: -> here is a link to the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-7sO--wzVZYQ3pyHTPhnyjMHzNy0jPBX

Comment: In that file your "foo" named ranges all end with an underscore, but the names used in your code do not.  If I fix that then it works as expected.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MwWKd0Ft_jBzDaKa_wdYm5U2jPz94hwa i tried changing the names to what i was working with instead of just providing an example, i still only get only 1 type of view to work. out of the three views listed, two get ignored and the one at the bottom of the code works without seeming to run the other views by seemingly bypassing it.. Sorry about all the questions, appreciate your help. (i uploaded a testing - 2 file) where these issues are prevalent

Comment: thanks very much for all your help Tim!! Was able to use the code you edited to make it work. one change i made (for others looking to solve the same issue) was change the rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "CustomView") line to rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = Target.Value) so that whatever the selection was ended up being executed. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I missed that line - see edit above.  All you need is `rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True`