# Runtime Error 1004 - BeforePrint - Avoid printing if cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to create a macro to prevent users from printing a form if they don't fill out all cells. However, I am getting an error message:

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
If Application.Sheets("Form").Range("B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4,M4,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5,M5,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6,L6,M6,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,M7,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9,B11,C11,D11,E11,F11,G11,H11,I11,B12,C12,D12,E12,F12,G12,H12,I12,B13,C13,D13,E13,F13,G13,H13,I13,B14,C14,D14,E14,F14,G14,H14,I14,B16,C16,D16,E16,F16,G16,H16,I16,B17,C17,D17,E17,F17,G17,H17,I17").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Fill out all the cells"
End If
End Sub
```

I have another macro for another form that has fewer cells and that one works just fine:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
If Application.Sheets("Form 2").Range("C4,C5,C6,D4,D5,D6,F4,F5,F6,B8,B9,B10,B11,C8,C9,C10,C11,D8,D9,D10,D11,E8,E9,E10,E11,C13,D13,C16,C17,C18,F16,F17,F18,C22,D22").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Fill out all the cells"
End If
End Sub
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: That second one really works?  BTW `Range("B4:M7")` is the same as `Range("B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,K4,L4,M4,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5,M5,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,K6,L6,M6,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,M7")`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer with better ranges, I should have noticed that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Range limit conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663264/range-limit-conundrum)

Comment: I marked this as a possible duplicate, because you say that your problem is getting the range to work but you should be aware that (as @TimWilliams comments) your second code sample is only running because it is only checking to see whether cell C4 is blank.  If C4 is filled in, but C5 is not, it won't display your MsgBox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a limit to line length or to how long of a string you can put into a range(). But you can consolidate it like this. Also I think that the return value from a range() with more than one cell is an array so I am not sure if it is valid to compare it to a string like you did.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    For Each cell In Application.Sheets("Form").Range("B4:M7,B8:I9,B11:I14,B16:I17")
        If cell.Value = "" Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "Fill out all the cells"
          Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this suggestion today and will let you know how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Now I am getting another error:
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: On what line is the error? When you get the error popup, click on debug and see what line is highlighted. I tested this code in a blank excel sheet named "Form" and it worked fine for me.

Comment: My bad, I was missing something from the code. Now, I am not getting any errors, however, I get the message "Fill out all the cells" even though I filled them out already. The cells that need to be filled out are:
From B4 to I4
From B5 to I5
From B7 to I9
From B11 to I14
From J4 to M7
From B16 to I17

I tried changing the range, but I kept getting the message "Fill out all the cells"

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: I created a sample sheet with your code and expected range and it worked as expected. However, I didn't rename the sheet to "Form" and simply used "Sheet1". Is it possible you're referring to the wrong sheet/name?

I'd suggest changing the Application.Sheets to ThisWorkbook.Sheets

Also, for more helpful feedback to the user, change your Msgbox line to something like:
          MsgBox "Fill out all the cells, missing value in " & cell.Address

Comment: No. Unfortunately, I am referring to the right sheet, so that's not the problem :(

Comment: I followed TravelinGuy's suggestion and I am getting this error message :  Fill out all the cells, missing value in $C$4.